# Search posts from a group of blogs

Tags: api, search, blogs

I was wondering if there is a way for me to search contents from a selected number of blogs.

For Example:

Assume I have three blogs

Blog1 (has 5 posts)
Blog2 (has 6 posts)
Blog3 (has 1 post)

now I want to implement a search that would search within these 12 (5+6+1) posts.

I think I need to use some kind of API for this but I dont know if there is one that would allow me to do this.

FYI the blog can be a blogger blog or a wordpress blog or any other kind of blog.

CAN ANYONE HELP ME OUT IN THIS ASPECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this. Most blogs have RSS feeds so you could fetch those and parse them. Some don't and you'll have to crawl them.

For a simple solution since you weren't very specific, check out [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/). It'll let you add those three or more blogs to your custom search and does all the backend work for you.

Of course, if you have more information then we could probably help you out a bit more.

Comment: Hey I was checking out the Google Custom Search and it has all the features that I was looking for. 
Thanks a lot for the help.